# show only video if the user's login page - Youtube

Tags: wordpress, youtube

This is how I got put this plugin on the page, and it is such that the videos which enters via youtube must be logged in to be able to see

http://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/

I've tried to throw this piece of code into the page, but it does not work quite as I want it.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
             echo "Member Content";
       }else{
             echo "Sorry Guest";
 ?>
```

as said content with video, could be shown when you are log into the site, so I hear some of you about something known to the revealed what line you should write the code into?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$userid = $user->id;
echo "User ID: " . $userid;
```